# How can I use the Winter Version of Summoners Rift?

Tags: league-of-legends, mods

In December 2011 there was a Winter Version of Summoners Rift. For those of you who don't know what I'm talking about here's a picture to jog your memory:[image: Winter Map]
[[Image Credit: LoL Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Summoner%27s_Rift#Winter_Version)]

The map (since it's from 2011) appears to be somewhat dated, but core parts of the map are the same (ie jungle locations, and bush places), so I think everything should fit properly. There are no options that I know of in-game to change this, but I know you can install custom skins or custom HUD's. Is there anyway for me to do this with map(s)? More importantly can I legally do this or what are my options?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was also there for December 2012. And it was available in custom games until Howling Abyss came to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this YouTube video's description](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7csJNzecf0) and [this thread](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=196489), whatever mod support for the winter map **is currently non-functional**, therefore making it currently impossible to install and run the winter map.

Answer (score 0):

The winter map is available only when Riot want it to be.

And i think that, if you can change the display of your game locally, you can't modify the map on which you are playing : It has to be the same for all players. (Since the last winter map, riot changed some things on Summoner's rift, like the chokes around baron nashor (red side) and drake (blue side)

So i think that if you can modify the map, it will be such bugs and it is illegal to do that.

Comment: Using the words "I think..." does not provide a substantive answer. Please attempt to be less biased.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested by me but should work.

You can install custom skins (for maps as well) by using [Skin Installer Ultimate (SIU)](https://sites.google.com/site/siuupdates/). A guide on how to configure SIU can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/siuupdates/).

The map can be found at [Yurixy Works](http://yurixyworks.com/). It's not the exact Winter Map but it's very alike. The map can be found [here](http://yurixyworks.com/2013/09/15/the-winter-is-back/). This website includes an install guide. For the installment, there is a video guide as well.

Using the SIU, you can add the downloaded zip file into the SIU. There is a note that you shouldn't forget to change the following setting:

> On SIU, go to Options > Edit All Preferences > Uncheck the option:
>   Fix Skin Textures with Format DXT3.

The program also has a thread on the official forums. You can find it [here](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2962049).

Be aware of updates of the game. It can change some points in the map thus leading to a bugged map. Keep an eye out for updates on the site.

Comment: Does it actually work?

Comment: @Aeronth This is untested by me but should work.

Comment: "Should"?? We need feedback on this. I think the differences between classic and winter versions are beyond simple graphical differences. If that is the case, LoL client will most likely crash during game start.

Comment: @Aeronth That's what has been said all the time already. As well as in my post. The original Winter map can not be gained, not even through 'illegal' ways or skinning, unless Riot makes it available. This post illustrates the thing that comes closest to a winter map.

Comment: Just as a note, a recent patch (maybe 3.10a) broke most of the existing skins.

Comment: @Sconibulus A few maps (like winter map) are fixed for 3.11+

Comment: Clearly you didn't bother testing any of this at all, because the maps work fine. Riot has said before that they are ok with modding, I'd love to see where they said it was "illegal", because that looks like it was pulled from thin air.

Comment: @Scootaloo I love how you are trying to be negative here. Please correctly read what I've stated. I'll try to explain again. I've stated that the ORIGINAL Winter Map can NOT be gained, whenever you try it legally or illegally. I've NEVER stated that it's illegal. This answer provides an ALTERNATIVE to the original map, which is skinning. I've also linked the OFFICIAL forum thread where Riot members state this form of skinning is LEGAL. I've also stated SOME maps do not work after the update but OTHER maps are updated so they DO work. Any other complaints?

Comment: Sidenote to everybody: I didn't test the winter map but some other maps, which screwed up my vision thus didn't work. It was a 3v3 map which should be fixed after the update. I don't have time to test the Winter Map so if anybody could give feedback on it, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I already tested the Winter Map, and it works fine. I wasn't trying to be negative, I just don't like it when people try spreading rumors/misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

The official winter map was created before the visual update to summoner's rift. Since they have not done a visual update to the winter map and so there is currently no official support for the winter map.